# How to add font loader to webpacker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

I am getting the following font load errors in webpacker:

```
Can't resolve './fonts/element-icons.woff' in '/Users/me/dev/projects/my-app/app/javascript/packs/styles'
```

How do you configure webpacker to get around this?

Comment: Maybe something you looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45489897/load-fonts-with-webpack-and-font-face

Comment: @TanDuong same, though i feel like in a real webpack setup these would've been sufficient