# webpack not loading @font-face

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, server-side-includes

in my React app i'm implementing server side rendering so i don't want to add `node_modules` in my server side because of performance issue.But i want `css` from from `node_modules` which are used as UI Kit libs.so i used webpack nodeExternal in my **webpack.server.config** file like

```
const path = require('path');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const baseConfig = require('./webpack.base.js');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')
let test = {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: 'css/locals?module&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
}   


const config = {
    target:'node',
    entry: './src/index.js',

    output:{
        filename:'bundle.js',
        path:path.resolve(__dirname,'build')
    },
    externals: [nodeExternals({
        whitelist: [/\.(?!(?:jsx?|json)$).{1,5}$/i]
    })]
}

module.exports  = merge(baseConfig,config)
```

here **webpack** adding css files but it is **not loading** @font-face from my node_modules UI kit files.if i remove **nodeExternal** from **webpack.server.config** file then every thing is working fine but `bundle.js` file size getting increased.
i already added *font rule* in my **webpack.base.config** file

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CSSExtract = new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css');


module.exports ={
    module: {
        rules: [{
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }, {
            test: /\.s?css$/,
            use: CSSExtract.extract({
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            })
        },{
            test: /\.(gif|svg|jpg|png|ttf|eot|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/,
            loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000&name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
        }
    ],
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    plugins: [
        CSSExtract
    ]
}
```

i tried with `file-loader` also but same problem
**it showing me error**

> @font-face {
>   ^
>   SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

**How can i add css files from node_modules with @font-face**

Comment: good tutorial for loading fonts, maybe it will help:
https://www.chriscourses.com/blog/loading-fonts-webpack

Comment: @VasylGutnyk i followed almost every thing that mention in that article

Comment: do you have loaders for css too?

Comment: @PlayMa256 yeah,css-loader and sass-loader

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load fonts with Webpack and font-face](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45489897/load-fonts-with-webpack-and-font-face)

Comment: @csilk i'm already using url loader, as he shown on ans

Answer (score 3):

here is webpack set up:

```
{
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "[name].[contenthash].[ext]",
              outputPath: "fonts/",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
```

then you have to import them to the css or scss main file.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  src: url("../../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Light.ttf");
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me, but in my case I had to separate the fonts file-loader from the assets file-loader with `jpeg|gif|png|svg|...` then it looked like a charm!