# @font-face SyntaxError when using typeface-nunito-sans and @poi/plugin-vue-static

Tags: vue.js, server-side-rendering

I'm using Poi, `@poi/plugin-vue-static` and `typeface-nunito-sans` to generate a static app using Vue. The problem is the build fails in a Syntax Error:

```
project/node_modules/typeface-nunito-sans/index.css:2
@font-face {
^
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

The whole app works correctly in dev server though. Is this because of the static site generation? How can I fix it?

Relevant code in main.ts:

```
// Client-side only libraries
import 'typeface-nunito-sans';
```

Comment: Sounds like a webpack problem. Maybe check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45489897/load-fonts-with-webpack-and-font-face

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by adding `process.client` check:

```
if (process.client) {
  require('typeface-nunito-sans');
}
```

This prevents CSS from being processed in server-side code