# ReactError: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, fonts

I have a local RobotoFont.tff which I am referencing in my index.scss file like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  src: url('src/assets/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
.rb {font-family: 'Roboto';}
```

But I am getting the following error at compile time:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/assets/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

The project is in React-Typescript and do I need to install any specific loaders as specified in the link? If yes does it work for .ttf files?

Comment: Did you try with this loader: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ttf-loader ?

Comment: Tried, added the package and added it in webpack too, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Take a look at this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45489897/load-fonts-with-webpack-and-font-face

Answer (score 4):

Just try [file-loader](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/) or [url-loader](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/url-loader/)

For example
webpack.config.js

```
     {
        test: /\.(png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
      },
```