# Webpack does not copy the images that i use into react components

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

hi i override the webpack of the create-react-app, in a separate override-webpack.ts file.

What i do is:

- bundle the js files and copy them into `build/static/js`
- bundle the css files and copy them into `build/static/css`
- **copy the /assets/img folder and copy them into `build/static/media`

**NOT all the images from `assets` folder are copied.The ones that are used into react components, are ignored, like so:
`<img width="34 src={${url}/img/car.svg} alt="car" />`

**Context:**

So all the js & css files are correctly bundled.
My issue is that the **images(png,svg)** from the `src/assets/img` are copied into `build/static/media`, are only the ones that are used into the `scss` files, and **NOT** from whithin my react **components**, these images are ignored, (**as i show above**), and that is what i looking for, **how to include them also in the build folder**

**my override-webpack.ts is like this:**.

```
var configurator = {
    paths(paths) {
      // paths
    },
 webpack(config, env) {
   //if stage, prod, dev
    bundleSass()
    addMedia()
    overrideOutput()
    return config;
  }
}

module.exports = configurator;


// overrride the publicPath of the bundles, so to have it into index.html
function overrideOutput(config) {
    config.output.filename = 'static/js/[name].[hash:8].js';
   config.output.chunkFilename = 'static/js/[name].[hash:8].chunk.js';
   config.output.publicPath = `http://www.something.com/`; // this is added into index.html
}


// copy images to build/static folder, i was hoping to copy the fonts as well but it does not..
// this functionality ONLY copies the images that are called into the css files,
// it IGNORES the images that used into react components,
// like: 
// <img width="34 src={`${url}/img/user.svg`} alt="user" />
function addMedia(config){
  const media = {
    test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg|png)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    use: [
     {
      loader: 'file-loader',
       options: {
        name: '[name].[ext]',
        outputPath: 'static/media', // by default it creates a media folder
       }
     }
    ]
 };

 config.module.rules.push( media ); // push the rule to the module array
}

// bundle scss files
function bundleSass(config) {
   // add rule for the sass-loader, so to bundle the scss files
}
```

Any suggestions why the images from inside the react components are not copied to the `build/static/media` is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that you are not importing the used images in React but just linking to them.
Try importing and using image files like so:

```
import CarImage from '../../img/car.svg';
// further down in the component
<img width="34 src={CarImage} alt="car" />
```

Now webpack should recognize the imports and write the files.

Comment: you are right. i just tried it.
the images are dynamic like : import car from `${assets)/img/car.svg` ;
this it can be a little challenging, but its something else.

Comment: also how about the fonts files. i use them inside the scss, but they are too, ignored.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45497292/3083470) might help you